# UISearchBar on UITableView strange offset issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UITableView` which has a `UISearchBar` subview. This is all on the view of a `UIViewController` along with a few other subviews (labels, text fields and such).

The search bar and content offset of the table are acting quite strangely, but it seems dependent on the order in which these views are added to the main view in the xib. I created a sample project with just my table/search and a label in order to test, and the result is the same. When the table is added *after* the label, everything works fine:

## Setup:

[image: table added after label]

## Correct and Expected Result:

[image: Proper expected result]

**However**, if I simply change the order in which my 2 subviews sit on the main view (aka table added *before* the label) then weird things start happening.

## Apparently bad setup:

[image: Table added before label]

## Weird offset of Search Bar:

[image: wtf is this?!?!]

I'm not changing anything else whatsoever, so why does Xcode seem to care which order these subviews are added to the main view?? If I scroll up on the "bad" table setup, the search bar disappears immediately at its top edge, but the table's content will continue to scroll up until it reaches the top of the frame that was set in the xib. Scroll back down and the search bar doesn't reappear until the strange lowered location. This is in Xcode 5.1.1, not the new beta. The result is the same with or without Autolayout turned on.

Any idea why this is happening? Is this a bug, or am I missing something? (I didn't post any code because all I'm doing is setting the number of sections, rows, and setting the text on the cell. Not messing with content insets, offset, anything. I load the view from the app delegate as the root of a nav controller)

Comment: Please add SearchBar on tableViewCell or tableView headerView.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This happens because a `UIViewController`'s property called `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`

> With iOS 7, UIViewControllers have a property called
>   automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets, and it defaults to YES. If you
>   have a scroll view that is either the root view of your view
>   controller (such as with a UITableViewController) or the subview at
>   index 0, then that property will adjust both the contentInset and the
>   scrollIndicatorInsets. This will allow your scroll view to start its
>   content and scroll indicators below the navigation bar (if your view
>   controller is in a navigation controller).

From [Big Nerd Ranch](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/designing-interfaces-ios-6-ios-7/)

If you are using storyboards, you can change it by selecting the view controller and in the attributes inspector deselect `Adjust scroll view insets`.

Here is its description from [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets):

> Default value is YES, which allows the view controller to adjust its
>   scroll view insets in response to the screen areas consumed by the
>   status bar, navigation bar, and toolbar or tab bar. Set to NO if you
>   want to manage scroll view inset adjustments yourself, such as when
>   there is more than one scroll view in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Can you be more specific on where this option is? I don't see it in the attributes inspector for the view controller, table view, or search bar (with or without autolayout)

Comment: I found out that you won't see it in xib files. It will only show in storyboards. Bus still you can set the 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' property in '-ViewDidLoad`

Comment: So, this does place the table at the correct location based on how it's set in the xib (regardless of the order in which it is added). I'm still curious as to WHY this is happening based on the order of the subviews in the xib. When the table is added second, it appears correct whether the scroll view insets are automatically adjusted or not. Why does it need to be set only if the table is first?

Comment: It only applies to scroll views (as subview) at index 0 or as the root view like UITableViewController. This [link](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/designing-interfaces-ios-6-ios-7/) confirms my theory.

Comment: That appears to be the info I was looking for! If you move this info into your answer, I'll mark it answered/bountied.

Comment: @Stonz2 the answer is not marked as bountied. Can you please, mark it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56148/discussion-between-stonz2-and-mustafa-ahmed).

Comment: Man, this was killing me. At least Reveal showed me what was happening so I could phrase the question and search properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem before about position of tableview and searchbar. i tried the following and it works for me.

If you do not write code for that and if it is only problem of xib or storyboard then try all outlet's autosizing and origin setting to fix its position and see the difference. it may be work for you.

[image]

Comment: That does not fix the issue. Besides, I know how to fix the issue (order the other subviews before the table) the question I have is WHY it's doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Update : `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` has been deprecated in ios 11 and a new field `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` has been introduced.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableview.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableView header can contains only one UIView, so if you need UISearchBar plus UILabel, you need to wrap they into UIView and add this view as UITableView header.

Comment: The label is not on the table view, it is sitting directly on the main view.