# UIWebview content not at top of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a iOS 9 screen with two UIWebviews on it; the two UIWebviews are set up the same in IB, and each displays an HTML table, with the same CSS. But the two views display differently: in the top one the table is scrolled down and shows a blank area at the top; the second one displays correctly.

The two HTML tables have a gray background to show their position here.
Here's the view when it opens; there is a table in each of the outlined UIWebviews:
[image]

I can manually scroll the top view into the correct position:

[image: Screen shot two]

I would, of course, like the top UIWebview to present the table at the top of the view.

Any ideas on why the top UIWebview scrolls the table down when it opens? I've seen this in several other instances and have not been able to figure out why or how to correct it.

Comment: Check this question that I asked a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335497/uisearchbar-on-uitableview-strange-offset-issue It probably has to do with the view being a scroll view and the first element in the list of subviews.

Comment: Thanks, Stonz2 - that fixed the problem! Just added         `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`
to the viewController's viewDidLoad method and it works as it should. I can't tell you how much I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Absolutely. Consider giving my question and the person who answered it an upvote so others can find it more easily.

Comment: Done on the upvotes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

Stonz2's link gave me the answer: add `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` to the viewController's viewDidLoad method.